# Modular Guess the game loop

Tags: python, loops

In my option 2 section of my code my loop isn't functioning properly and i can not figure out why. It keeps asking for an input again. I tried moving the input outside of the loop but that didn't work either.

```
 import random      

def display_menu():
        print("Welcome to my Guess the Number Program!")
        print("1. You guess the number")
        print("2. You type a number for the computer to guess.")
        print("3. Exit")
        print()

def main():
    display_menu()
    option = int(input("Enter a menu option: "))
```

User pics a number randomly generated by the computer until user gets
 the correct answer.
 Outputs user guesses and number of attempts until guessed correct

```
    if option == 1:

        number = random.randint(1,10)
        counter = 0

        while True:
            try:        
                guess = input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ")
                guess = int(guess)
                print()
                if guess < 1 or guess > 10:
                    raise ValueError()
                counter += 1
                if guess > number:
                    print("Too high.")
                    print()
                elif guess < number:
                    print("Too low.")
                    print()
                else:
                    print("You guessed it!")
                    print("You guessed the number in", counter, "attempts!")
                    break
            except ValueError:
                print(guess, "is not a valid guess")
                print()
```

Option 2., User enters a number for the computer to guess.
 Computer guesses a number within the range given.
 Outputs computer guesses and number of guesses until computer gets
 the correct number.

```
    if option == 2:
        print("Computer guess my number")
        print()


        while True:
            try:
                my_num = input("Enter a number between 1 and 10 for the computer to guess: ")
                my_num = int(my_num)
                counter = 0
                counter += 1
                print()
                comp = random.randint(1,10)
                if my_num < 1 or my_num > 10:
                    raise ValueError()

                if comp > my_num:
                    print("Computer guessed", comp,"to High")

                elif comp < my_num:
                    print("Computer guessed", comp,"to Low")

                else:
                    print("Computer guessed the right number!" , comp)
                    print("Computer guessed the right number in", counter, "attempts!")
                    break

            except ValueError:
                print(my_num, "is not a valid entry")
                print()
                continue
    """
    Ends game
    """
    if option == 3:
        print("Goodbye")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for input *before* the loop. `counter` should be initialised before the loop too.

```
if option == 2:
    print("Computer guess my number")
    print()

    # these three lines will be run once before the loop
    my_num = input("Enter a number between 1 and 10 for the computer to guess: ")
    my_num = int(my_num)
    counter = 0

    while True:
        try:
            comp = random.randint(1,10)
            counter += 1
            print()
            if my_num < 1 or my_num > 10:
                raise ValueError()

            if comp > my_num:
                print("Computer guessed", comp,"to High")

            elif comp < my_num:
                print("Computer guessed", comp,"to Low")

            else:
                print("Computer guessed the right number!" , comp)
                print("Computer guessed the right number in", counter, "attempts!")
                break

        except ValueError:
            print(my_num, "is not a valid entry")
            print()
            continue
```

As an aside, instead of randomly guessing, you can improve the computer's guessing by using [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), where the number of tries has an upper bound.